# Bootstrap Carousel cannot resize image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use Carousel in bootstrap it show image larger than original image. I want to resize image of Carousel. This is my code.

```css
.carousel .item.left img{
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="/media/images/02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="/media/images/05.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I try to resize to 80% but it still show same size. How to fix it ?

Comment: `<script>` with CSS in it ? Are you sure. Its SHOULD BE `<style>`

Comment: Where is `.carousel` class in your HTML ? You want  `.carousel-item img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct it as

```
<style >
 .carousel-item > img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
    

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/media/images/02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/media/images/05.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It didn't work for you because you had put your CSS inside of `<script></script>` tags instead of `<style></style>` tags. This should work well.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .carousel-item>img {
    width: 80% !important;
  }
</style>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>

  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="/media/images/02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/media/images/05.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```